# Cannot Update database value

Tags: php, mysql

This my code. I want to update my database value. But it doesn't work.
I want to update status from (pending) to (borrowed) AND from (returnP) to (returned).

This is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['gate']))
{
    extract($_GET);
    $timestamp=date("d/m/y h:i:sA",time());
    $sql = "SELECT *FROM rent_record WHERE pass_open='$gate'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $name = $row["ID"];
    $status = $row["status"];


    if (($gate==$name) AND ( $status=='pending'))

    {       
    $sql = "UPDATE rent_record SET status='borrowed' WHERE ID='$name';";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) header('Location: '.BASE_URL.'/keypad');
    else echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;     

    $sql = "UPDATE rent_record SET time_taken='$timestamp' WHERE ID='$name';";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) header('Location: '.BASE_URL.'/keypad');
    else echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;     
}
else if (($gate==$name) AND ( $status=='returnP'))
{   
    $sql = "UPDATE rent_record SET status='returned' WHERE ID='$name';";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) header('Location: '.BASE_URL.'/keypad');
    else echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;     

    $sql = "UPDATE rent_record SET time_return='$timestamp' WHERE ID='$name';";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) header('Location: '.BASE_URL.'/keypad');
    else echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
}
}
else
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $sql = "SELECT pass_open, pass_closed FROM rent_record WHERE status='pending' OR status='returnP'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $outp = '[';
    while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        if ($outp != '[') {$outp .= ',';}
        $outp .= '{"ID":"' . $rs['ID'] . '",'; 
        $outp .= '"password":"' . $rs['pass_open'] . '"}'; 
        $outp .= '"password":"' . $rs['pass_closed'] . '"}'; 
    }
    $outp .=']';

    echo($outp);
}
```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: *"doesn't work"*? Does it result in an error? Do you know how to control error reporting?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Using `extract()` is not recommended on `$_GET`

Comment: At what point does this go wrong? At first glance, I see a syntax error in your first query: `SELECT *FROM` (missing a space after the `*`). Not sure if that's the problem, if you get an error message it should indicate a line number.

Comment: You're also vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code. You should ***ALWAYS*** use prepared statements

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli_` functions, you should **ALWAYS** use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and the function [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to protect against SQL-Injections. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because it creates a severe SQL injection bug. **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data into a query directly. This can be very harmful if someones seeks to exploit your mistake.